# ASP.NET MVC : How to bind dropdown list with nested list type property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

here is my full code. who will see it then they could understand what i am trying to achieve. after seeing my code if anyone think there is problem in code design then please discuss with rectified version.

### view model and model code

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public int SelectedState = 0;
    public int SelectedCity = 0;
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = "";
    public int StateID = 0;
    public int CityID = 0;
    public List<States> States { get; set; }
    public List<Cities> Cities { get; set; }

}

public class States
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = "";
}

public class Cities
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = "";
}
```

Controller code from where i am populating my view model and model

```
    public ActionResult Index()
        {

            MainViewModel oVm = new MainViewModel()
            {
                Students = new List<Student>() {
                    new Student
                    {
                        ID=1,
                        Name="JoyDev",
                        StateID=1,
                        CityID=1,
                        States=new List<States>()
                        {
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="WestBengal",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Bihar",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Orrisa",
                            }

                        },
                        Cities=new List<Cities>()
                        {
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="Alipur"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Asansol"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Andul"
                            }

                        }
                    },

//***********
                    new Student
                    {
                        ID=1,
                        Name="Mukti",
                        StateID=2,
                        CityID=1,
                        States=new List<States>()
                        {
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="WestBengal",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Bihar",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Orrisa",
                            }

                        },
                        Cities=new List<Cities>()
                        {
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="Janpur"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Madhubani"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Kanti"
                            }

                        }
                    },
//***********
                    new Student
                    {
                        ID=1,
                        Name="Somnath",
                        StateID=3,
                        CityID=2,
                        States=new List<States>()
                        {
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="WestBengal",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Bihar",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Orrisa",
                            }

                        },
                        Cities=new List<Cities>()
                        {
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="Chandapur"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Dhankauda"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Konarak"
                            }

                        }
                    }


                }

            };

            return View();
        }
```

view code where i was trying to bind drop down.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MainViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>City</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var m in Model.Students)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="@m.ID" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="@m.Name" /></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("CityID", new SelectList(ViewData["CityList"] as List<SelectListItem>, "Value", "Text", m.CityID))
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState new SelectList(Model.Students.States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCity new SelectList(Model.Students.Cities, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCity), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

### main problem lies here

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState new SelectList(Model.Students.States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })
```

main question is how to bind drop down with nested list type property `Model.Students.States`.
 thanks

Comment: Its a bit unclear from your model what your trying to select/bind to. Currently you bind each `Student` only to the `SelectedState` of `MainViewModel` - i.e. if you select an option in one dropdownlist, then select an option in another dropownlist, it overwrites the selection you made in the first one

Comment: i am not after cascade dropdown. in very row i want to show studen name, state data in dropdown and also city data in dropdown but i want to load only those city data in dropdown based on student state id.

Comment: suppose in webform if i need to show student data in gridview then we can bound gridview with student data and gridview 
has rowdata bound event from that event we can populate state data in state dropdown in each gridview row and same
way we can populate city data in city drop down but when we load city data then we can pass student stateid and as a 
result in each row only few city data will be populated in dropdown as per student state id.

the same i want to achieve in MVC generating table with dropdown. now see my code and tell what to change in my
code to achieve it. thanks

Comment: That not the point I was making - your binding each Students state to a single property - only the first students state will ever be bound to `SelectedState` (and ditto for `SelectedCity`). I'm not sure what your wanting to do. Best guess is you want to bind to `CityID` and `StateId` properties of `Student` model

Comment: sorry not clear what u r trying to say. would u plzz tell me how to bind dropdown with nested list type property? `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState new SelectList(Model.Students.States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })` just tell me how could i write this line in dropdown `Model.Students.States`

Comment: @StephenMuecke if you understand what kind of output i am looking for then please post some sample code to achieve what i am trying to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand, but my best guess is you want `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count; i++) { @Hml.DropDownListFor(m => m.Students[i].StateID, new SelectList(Model.Students[i].States, "ID", "Name"), "-- Select States--", new {  @class = "edit-mode" }) }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you understand correctly but now i will move to 2nd question that when we work with webgrid then i guess we can not write this syntax `@Hml.DropDownListFor(m => m.Students[i].StateID, new SelectList(Model.Students[i].States, "ID", "Name"), "-- Select States--", new { @class = "edit-mode" })` for webgrid how could i show student wise state or city details?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with webgrid, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520958/how-to-use-dropdownlist-binded-to-model-inside-webgrid-razor-asp-net-mvc-4) shows how it can be done (and the reason I don't use its is because I agree with Darin's comments)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks but they use DropDownList but i need to use DropDownListFor so can u tell me how the syntax will look like for DropDownListFor with model[0] ?

Comment: AFAIK, You cant use `DropDownListFor()` with webgrid (as Darin pointer out, its crap)

Comment: i use DropDownListFor in webgrid and it worked. why he thinks DropDownListFor can not go with webgrid ? any suggestion

Comment: You may be using a later version that now supports it

Answer (score 3):

My issue has been solved. so i like to give my updated code because the same code may help other.

### my viewmodel and model classes

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public int SelectedState = 0;
    public int SelectedCity = 0;
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = "";
    public int StateID = 0;
    public int CityID = 0;
    public List<States> States { get; set; }
    public List<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class States
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cities
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller from where i populate my model

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MainViewModel oVm = new MainViewModel()
            {
                Students = new List<Student>() {
                    new Student
                    {
                        ID=1,
                        Name="JoyDev",
                        StateID=1,
                        CityID=1,
                        States=new List<States>()
                        {
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="WestBengal",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Bihar",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Orrisa",
                            }

                        },
                        Cities=new List<Cities>()
                        {
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="Alipur"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Asansol"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Andul"
                            }

                        }
                    },

//***********
                    new Student
                    {
                        ID=1,
                        Name="Mukti",
                        StateID=2,
                        CityID=1,
                        States=new List<States>()
                        {
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="WestBengal",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Bihar",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Orrisa",
                            }

                        },
                        Cities=new List<Cities>()
                        {
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="Janpur"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Madhubani"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Kanti"
                            }

                        }
                    },
//***********
                    new Student
                    {
                        ID=1,
                        Name="Somnath",
                        StateID=3,
                        CityID=2,
                        States=new List<States>()
                        {
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="WestBengal",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Bihar",
                            },
                            new States
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Orrisa",
                            }

                        },
                        Cities=new List<Cities>()
                        {
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=1,
                                Name="Chandapur"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=2,
                                Name="Dhankauda"
                            },
                            new Cities
                            {
                                ID=3,
                                Name="Konarak"
                            }

                        }
                    }


                }

            };

            return View(oVm);
        }


    }
```

### view code

```
@model BuildTable.Models.MainViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>City</td>
    </tr>
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="@Model.Students[i].ID" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="@Model.Students[i].Name" /></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Students[i].StateID, new SelectList(Model.Students[i].States, "ID", "Name",Model.Students[i].StateID), "-- Select States--", new { @class = "edit-mode" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Students[i].CityID, new SelectList(Model.Students[i].Cities, "ID", "Name",Model.Students[i].CityID), "-- Select Cities--", new { @class = "edit-mode" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Models:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class ViewInfo
    {
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public int? CityID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int CityID { get; set; }
    }
    public class State
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public Class City
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
using MyProject.Models;
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private MyDBEntities _context;

        public StudentsController()
        {
            this._context = new MyDBEntities();
        }

        // StudentsController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.ViewInfo = new ViewInfo { StateID = 1 };
            ViewBag.StateID = _context.States.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name }).ToList();
            return View(_context.Students.ToList());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(ViewInfo viewInfo)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            ViewBag.ViewInfo = viewInfo;
            ViewBag.StateID = _context.States.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name, Selected = s.ID == viewInfo.StateID }).ToList();
            ViewBag.CityID = _context.Cities.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name, Selected = s.ID == viewInfo.CityID ?? 1 }).ToList();

            var viewModel = _context.Students.Where(s => s.Cities.StateID == viewInfo.StateID && (viewInfo.CityID == null || s.CityID == viewInfo.CityID)).ToList();

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

And the View:

```
@using MyProject.Models;
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students";
    ViewInfo viewInfo = ViewBag.ViewInfo;
}

<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Students</h2>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    @Html.DropDownList("StateID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })

    if(viewInfo.CityID != null){ @Html.DropDownList("CityID", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) }

    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" />

    // Students Table
}
```

Comment: where is the dropdown for city ?