# ASP.Net MVC: How to bind dropdown with deep nested property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

suppose below is my view model classes.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public int SelectedState = 0;

}

public class Student
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = "";
    public int StateID = 0;
    public List<States> States { get; set; }

}

public class States
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = "";
}
```

now how could i bind dropdown with nested property called States of student class ?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState new SelectList(Model.Students.States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })
```

this is not working `SelectList(Model.Students.States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState)` how to refer this `Model.Students.States`

please discuss this issue with code sample. each student has relation with states.

Comment: try to use selectmany linq extension Model.Students.SelectMany(x=>x..States)

Comment: please confirm does this code will work `
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState new SelectList(Model.Students.SelectMany(x=>x.States), 
"ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })` ?

Comment: I doubt whether your model is constructed properly, why should `Student` object should have `List<State>`? can you tell us what is your actual requirement, so that we can propose a solution?

Comment: @Mou I didn't test this code, but i think it will work

Comment: student has relation with state. each student belong to single state but i need to show all state name in dropdown for each student that is why i design it this way. if it is wrong then come a right design code. thanks

Comment: @Mou i agree with "ramiramilu" decision, according to  your requirement Student should have State property not List<State> ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis would you code with new class design code?

Comment: @Mou same code no big changes Model.Students.SelectMany(x=>x..State) and you have to write class like  public State State { get; set; } instead of  public List<States> States { get; set; }

Comment: @Mou, are you trying to create a new `student`?

Comment: how this code can return more state info ` public State State { get; set; } ` which i want to load into dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.Students.FirstOrDefault().States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })
```

But its better to save States List in ViewBag in your Controller:

```
ViewBag.States = (_context or _serviceLayer).(States or GetStates()).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name, Selected = s.ID == viewModel.SelectedState }).ToList();
```

And on View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.States, "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })
```

**REQUESTED EDIT:**

Models:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class ViewInfo
    {
        public int StateID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int StateID { get; set; }
    }
    public class State
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
using MyProject.Models;
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private MyDBEntities _context;

        public StudentsController()
        {
            this._context = new MyDBEntities();
        }

        // StudentsController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.ViewInfo = new ViewInfo { StateID = 1 };
            ViewBag.StateID = _context.States.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name }).ToList();
            return View(_context.Students.ToList());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(ViewInfo viewInfo)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            ViewBag.ViewInfo = viewInfo;
            ViewBag.StateID = _context.States.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ID, Text = s.Name, Selected = s.ID == viewInfo.StateID }).ToList();
            return View(_context.Students.Where(s => s.StateID == viewInfo.StateID).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

And the View:

```
@using MyProject.Models;
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students";
    ViewInfo viewInfo = ViewBag.ViewInfo;
}

<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Students</h2>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    @Html.DropDownList("StateID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" />

    // Students Table
}
```

Comment: would mind to help bit more. would please see view model and post new view model classes what u think would be right.

Comment: leave answer for this post rather give answer for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709891/asp-net-mvc-how-to-bind-dropdown-list-with-nested-list-type-property?noredirect=1#comment57181291_34709891

Comment: my objective is to show student data in tabular format. data would look like Name, state dropdown, city dropdown, state will load independenctly but city will load based on student state id. how to achieve it.

Comment: are you still there or online?

Comment: Yup, done ^^, that's how i do, but instead of _context in controllers i prefer creating Service and Data Layers ;) gonna check another you post.

Comment: can't we use DropDownListFor to bind it with model ?

Comment: i do not want to use ViewBag too.

Comment: if you want List items for DropDown inputs you should use ViewBag.

Comment: no, we can use directly bind dropdownlistfor helper with view model.

Comment: You can, but i am saying correct way is to have DropDownList data in ViewBag, its not correct to add States list model to students model and than use it for filling dropdownlist...

Comment: may be u r correct but if some one have good hold on mvc then they can do it. i am weak in mvc and that is why i stuck. if u know it then please share the idea with code sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100366/discussion-between-quietnan-and-mou).