# Applying cascading to dropdownlist in a column in asp.net mvc with razor view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am facing an issue . I have a view which has two columns of dropdownlists inside a webgrid. One of the column is for selecting multiple table names from the dropdown. the second column is supposed to cascade with the first column and return the column names for the tables chosen in the first column. I managed to cascade it for the first row but somehow it doesn't work for the remaining columns in the column names dropdown. 
I am enumerating the table name from the model. Based on table name i use javascript to cascade the columnnames which only works for the first row. Please advice on how i can cascade it for all the dropdowns in the column

My View Code for the dropdown is as follow:

```
 <div id="grid">
    @wg.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
            rowStyle: "gridRow",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
            alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
    columns: wg.Columns(
                         wg.Column("DestnColumn", "Destination Column"),
                                          wg.Column("SourceTable", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceColumnModel[0].SourceTables,"Select Source")),
                                                   wg.Column("ColumnNames", format:@item=> Html.DropDownList("ColumnNames",new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { style = "width:200px" })),
                               // wg.Column(header: "SourceColumn", format: @item1 => Html.DropDownList("value1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceColumnModel[0].SourceColumnsNames)),
                                         wg.Column("DataSize", "Size"),
                                 wg.Column("DataType", "Data Type"))

)
    )
</div>
```

My Javascript is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#SourceTable").change(function () {
        $("#ColumnNames").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetColumn")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { TableName: $("#SourceTable option:selected").text() },
            success: function (str) {
                $.each(str, function (Value, Text) {
                    //alert(Value + ' ' + Text.Value);
                    $("#ColumnNames").append('<option value ="'+Value+ '">' +
                    Text.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve columns.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

My Method that returns JSON is as follow:

```
public JsonResult GetColumn(string TableName)
{    ArrayList id1 = new ArrayList();
List<SelectListItem> str = new List<SelectListItem>();
var temp = (from m in db.inputs where m.input_name == TableName select m).First<input>().input_id;
ArrayList FieldName = new ArrayList();
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
var s = (from m in db.input_field where m.input_id == id select m.input_field_name);
var i =(from m in db.input_field where m.input_id == id select m.input_field_id);
int j = 0;
foreach(int iq in i)
{

    id1.Add(j);
    j++;
}
foreach (string Field in s)
{
    FieldName.Add(Field);
}
for(j =0; j< id1.Count; j++)
{
    str.Add(new SelectListItem{Text= FieldName[j].ToString(),Value = id1[j].ToString() });
}

return Json(new SelectList(str, "Value", "Text"));
}
```

Please advice on the same

[the HTML rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgpMw.png)

the code for rendering html is as follow:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SelectSrcAndDestn - Quick Analytics - Dashboard</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="/">your logo here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                        <ul>
    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("select.dropdownSource").live("change", (function () {
        $("select.clsColumnNames").empty();

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetColumn',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { TableName: $(this).find("option:selected").text() },
            success: function (str) {

                $.each(str, function (Value, Text) {
                    //alert(Value + ' ' + Text.Value);
                    $(".clsColumnNames").append('<id ="' + Value + '"/>')
                    $(".clsColumnNames").append('<option value ="' + Value + '">' +
                    Text.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve columns.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
)});

</script>














<style type="text/css">
    .gridTable {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px #333 solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        min-width: 550px;
        background-color: #999;
        color: #999;
    }

.gridHead th {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffd800;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gridHead a:link, .gridHead a:visited, .gridHead a:active, .gridHead a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.gridHead a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #f67f7f;
}

.gridTable tr.gridAltRow {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}

.gridTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #f67f7f;
}

.gridAltRow td {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #333;
}

.gridRow td {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
}

.gridFooter td {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridFooter a {
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px #333 solid;
}
</style>





<div id="grid">
        <table class="gridTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="gridHead">
        <th scope="col">
<a href="/Home/SelectSrcAndDestn?sort=DestnColumn&amp;sortdir=ASC">Destination Column</a>            </th>
        <th scope="col">
<a href="/Home/SelectSrcAndDestn?sort=SourceTable&amp;sortdir=ASC">SourceTable</a>            </th>
        <th scope="col">
<a href="/Home/SelectSrcAndDestn?sort=ColumnNames&amp;sortdir=ASC">ColumnNames</a>            </th>
        <th scope="col">
<a href="/Home/SelectSrcAndDestn?sort=DataSize&amp;sortdir=ASC">Size</a>            </th>
        <th scope="col">
<a href="/Home/SelectSrcAndDestn?sort=DataType&amp;sortdir=ASC">Data Type</a>            </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>Even Date Time</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridAltRow">
        <td>Even End Time</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>BP Systolic</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridAltRow">
        <td>BP Diastolic</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>BMI</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridAltRow">
        <td>Patient ID</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>Age</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridAltRow">
        <td>Ethnicity</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>Triglyceride Level</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridAltRow">
        <td>Hypertension</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>Family History</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridAltRow">
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td>HDL </td>
        <td><select class="dropdownSource" id="SourceTable" name="SourceTable" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Source</option>
<option value="1">TableNames</option>
<option value="2">Destination1</option>
<option value="3">Destination2</option>
</select></td>
        <td><select class="clsColumnNames" id="ColumnNames" name="ColumnNames" style="width:200px"><option value="">Select Column</option>
</select></td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>VARCHAR</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    )
</div>


        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; 2016 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
{"appName":"Internet Explorer","requestId":"4318bb18b7eb41148557001228ec92d8"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:50502/b2cd8ef3124349f89d598fb5cd5073f2/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

the updated Javascript as 12/01/2016

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("select.dropdownSource").live("change", (function () {
        var columnSelectBox = $(this).parent("td").find("select.clsColumnNames");
        $(columnSelectBox).empty();

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetColumn',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { TableName: $(this).find("option:selected").text() },
            success: function (str) {

                $.each(str, function (Value, Text) {
                    //alert(Value + ' ' + Text.Value);

                    $(".clsColumnNames").append('<option value ="' + Value + '">' +
                    Text.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve columns.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
)});
```

the Html WebGrid View as 12/01/2016:

```
<div id="grid">
    @wg.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
            rowStyle: "gridRow",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
            alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
    columns: wg.Columns(
                         wg.Column("DestnColumn", "Destination Column"),
                                                   wg.Column("SourceTable", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceColumnModel[0].SourceTables, "Select Source", new { style = "width:200px", @class = "dropdownSource" })),
                                                            wg.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnName", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new {id= string.Empty, style = "width:200px", @class = "clsColumnNames" })),
                               // wg.Column(header: "SourceColumn", format: @item1 => Html.DropDownList("value1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceColumnModel[0].SourceColumnsNames)),
                                         wg.Column("DataSize", "Size"),
                                 wg.Column("DataType", "Data Type"))

)
    )
</div>
```

the Json Method returning the column names as on 12/01/2015

```
public JsonResult GetColumn(string TableName)
{    ArrayList id1 = new ArrayList();
List<SelectListItem> str = new List<SelectListItem>();
var temp = (from m in db.inputs where m.input_name == TableName select m).First<input>().input_id;
ArrayList FieldName = new ArrayList();
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
var s = (from m in db.input_field where m.input_id == id select m.input_field_name);
var i =(from m in db.input_field where m.input_id == id select m.input_field_id);
int j = 0;
foreach(int iq in i)
{

    id1.Add(j);
    j++;
}
foreach (string Field in s)
{
    FieldName.Add(Field);
}
for(j =0; j< id1.Count; j++)
{
    str.Add(new SelectListItem{Text= FieldName[j].ToString(),Value = id1[j].ToString() });
}

return Json(new SelectList(str, "Value", "Text"));
}
```

Comment: the element should have different id's for each elements.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis ... i wasnt able to add it as such inside this webgrid... any suggestion on how i can do it ??

Comment: you have to create different ID's for each dropdownlist and set one common class also.  So we can use it by using classes instead of ID's

Comment: Set class for the each dropdownlist using Html.DropDownList("ColumnNames",new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { @class="clsColumnNames", style = "width:200px" })

Comment: can you also tell me on how to change the Javascript accordingly ... new to javascript hence a little confused

Comment: ok first you need to set classes for the dropdownlist as i mentioned in the previous chat

Comment: thats set now ...just added the class

Comment: ok then replace the line  $("#SourceTable").change(function () { to  $("select.{classname}").live("change",(function () {});

Comment: then change the line to data: { TableName: $(this).find("option:selected").text() },

Comment: And can you please post the rendered Html of that Web Grid So it's easy to write the scripts

Comment: @FrebinFrancis ... attaching the rendered page to the following

Comment: I Made the changes and now whenever i change the table name all the columns get affected

Comment: yes we can solve that also

Comment: we need to correct this line  $("#ColumnNames").append('<option value ="'+Value+ '">' + Text.Text + '</option>');

Comment: Can you please update your question with the rendered Html of the webgrid ? Then only i can make other changes

Comment: @FrebinFrancis ... i have added the rendered Html of the webgrid to the post

Comment: No. i want to see the html source code not the image

Comment: @FrebinFrancis ... i have added the code rendered to this post

Comment: Yes i saw that, Could you please update your dropdownlist helper as Html.DropDownList("ColumnNames",new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id=string.empty, @class="clsColumnNames", style = "width:200px" })

Comment: To Set the ID as empty for each dropdownlist. Or check this link to assign unique ID's for each dropdownlist in webgrid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520958/how-to-use-dropdownlist-binded-to-model-inside-webgrid-razor-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: @FrebinFrancis  ... i changed it as follow .   wg.Column("ColumnNames", format: item => Html.DropDownList(((int)item.Value).ToString(), new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new {id= string.Empty, style = "width:200px", class = "clsColumnNames" }))..................... It Didnt Work :(

Comment: I added answer to make the jquery scripts clear. Please see it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my Jquery Script below for updating the columns dropdown

```
$("select.dropdownSource").live("change", (function () {
  var columnSelectBox = $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("select.clsColumnNames");
  $(columnSelectBox).empty();

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetColumn',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { TableName: $(this).find("option:selected").text() },
            success: function (str) {

          $.each(str, function (Value, Text) {
             $(columnSelectBox).append('<option value ="' + Value + '">' +
             Text.Text + '</option>');
             });
         },
         error: function (ex) {
             alert('Failed to retrieve columns.' + ex);
         }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: It Worked but now the issue that happened it if i choose table1 in first drop down and choose the respective column name... goto next dropdown and choose table2 and i still get columns in table 1 in the dropdown for the respective columns... @FrebinFrancis

Comment: Is there any filtering of data that happens when you call ajax method "GetColumns" ?

Comment: nope ... it takes the dropdown selected Table name and passes it to ajax method GetColumn and based on that the column names for that table are returned

Comment: Are you sure the columns belongs to the selected table only ?

Comment: yes that is what should come up but here now that happens is when i choose table1 then col1 comes up in the dropdown, when i chose table2 in the next drop down then col1 of table1 comes along with col2 of table 2 in the dropdown...

Comment: Can you please update your question with only the latest code and html which i gave you ?

Comment: I have edited the post with todays date 12/01/2015 @Frebin Francis

Comment: Please see my updated answer as i changed some lines on that ajax call code

Comment: Changes in line var columnSelectBox = $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("select.clsColumnNames");

Comment: it worked ... thanks a lot :) ... got to learn a lot from you :)

Comment: you are always welcome. Please dont forget to vote for the answer :)

Comment: hi I have something similar, with country, and then the state cascading. My question is - *Hi what if the country was NOT changed, and I ONLY want to change the second col the `state` DropDown?* how can that retrieve/trigger