# ASP.Net MVC: Webgrid and dropdown binding with model array like approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc

just see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521169/728750

```
grid.Column(
    "TodosLosRoles", 
    "Roles", 
    format: item => Html.DropDownList(((int)item.UserId).ToString(), Model[0].TodosLosRoles)
)
```

if i write the above code `Model[0].TodosLosRoles` then how could i specify model ordinal position instead of hard code value 0.

can i use for loop here ?

```
for(int i=0; i <= model.students.count-1;i++)
{

    grid.Column(
        "TodosLosRoles", 
        "Roles", 
        format: item => Html.DropDownList(((int)item.UserId).ToString(), Model[i].TodosLosRoles)
    )}
```

does above kind of code will work.....not sure. need suggestion. thanks

Comment: So, in each row of the grid, you have a dropdown, and you want the items of the dropdown to be unique to each row?

Comment: i just like to know how this kind of syntax `Model[0].TodosLosRoles` can be used with webgrid. in this syntax i hard code first element in array but i like to know what i can do as a result one after one element will be extracted from array when webgrid will create each row.